# Tinymce preview plugin - extra regex formatting

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I was wondering if anyone is aware of any way to add extra formatting when opening Tinymce preview using preview plugin?

Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find the same solution and found your question.

I looked in the plugin code and wasn't able to find any hooks, to solve the issue I've overwritten the command of preview plugin with the following code

```js
// needed only if editor is not in the scope
var editor = tinymce.activeEditor;

// check if plugin is active for this instance
if (editor.getParam('plugins').match(/\bpreview\b/)) {
    editor.addCommand('mcePreview', function() {
        editor.windowManager.open({
            // paste code from original "preview" plugin
            // do your stuff here
            // there's a "doc" variable avaliable
            // which points to the iframe document in preview window
        });
    });
}
```

Note: i'm running TinyMCE 4